# Acute angle between two planes

Tags: linear-algebra

The acute angle between two planes is called the dihedral angle. Plane $x - 3y + 2z = 0$ and plane $3x-2y-z+3 = 0$ intersect in a line and form a dihedral angle $\theta$ . Find a third plane (in point-normal, i.e. component, form) through the point $(\frac67,0,\frac37)$ that has dihedral angle $\frac{\theta}2$ with each of the original planes. Do the three planes intersect at a point or in a line? Explain all
steps carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Given normal vectors $\vec n_1$ and $\vec n_2$ to planes $P_1,P_2$, the dihedral angle between $P_1,P_2$ is the acute angle $\theta$ such that $$\cos\theta=\frac{|\vec n_1\cdot\vec n_2|}{\lVert\vec n_1\rVert\lVert\vec n_2\rVert},$$ if such a $\theta$ exists.

A normal vector to $x-3y+2z=0$ is $\vec n_1=(1,-3,2)$ and a normal vector to $3x-2y-z+3=0$ is $\vec n_2=(3,-2,-1).$ We can use this to find $\cos\theta$, and observe that $\cos\frac\theta2=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}2}.$ Now take a general non-zero vector $\vec v=(x,y,z)$ and determine when $$\cos\frac\theta2=\frac{|\vec n_1\cdot\vec v|}{\lVert\vec n_1\rVert\lVert\vec v\rVert}=\frac{|\vec n_2\cdot\vec v|}{\lVert\vec n_2\rVert\lVert\vec v\rVert}.$$ That will give you a normal vector for your third plane. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks I understand it now!