# Angle between two planes: $ x+2y-6 $ and $ y=0 $

Tags: vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

Plane 1: $x + 2y - 6 = 0$

Plane 2: $y = 0$

--

I can see that the normal vector of the first plane is {1, 2, 0} but what would be the the normal vector of the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acute angle between two planes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/345030/acute-angle-between-two-planes)

Comment: It might be worth pointing that a "plan" is the outline of what you will do for the rest of the day (or so), and a "plane" is a two-dimensional space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the plane $ax+by+cz=d$ the normal is $(a, b, c)$. For the plane $y = 0$ we may write $ 0x+1y+0z=0$. Hence the normal is $\boxed{(0, 1, 0)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first normal vector is not correct.
The normal vector should be $(1, 2, 0)$

You might ask: Why we do not coins $6$? No matter what constant we take, those planes are parallel, and thus have the same normal vector.

In terms of the second equation, write it as 
$$0\cdot x + 1 \cdot y + 0 \cdot z = 0$$

Could you find its normal vector?